# The limit of $(4-\sqrt{16-7\sin(x)})/(8x)$ at zero without using L'Hôpital

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I stumbled across this silly limit and I am perplexed at how I can arrive to a solution by only relying on the simplest rules of limits.

$$
\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{4-\sqrt{16-7\sin(x)}}{8x}
$$

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can have $$\frac{4-\sqrt{16-7\sin x}}{8x}=\frac{(4-\sqrt{16-7\sin x})\color{red}{(4+\sqrt{16-7\sin x})}}{8x\color{red}{(4+\sqrt{16-7\sin x})}}$$
$$=\frac{7\sin x}{8x(4+\sqrt{16-7\sin x})}=\frac 78\cdot \frac{\sin x}{x}\cdot\frac{1}{4+\sqrt{16-7\sin x}}.$$
Here, note that $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1.$$

Answer (score 2):

Multiply the numerator and denominator by $4+\sqrt{16-7\sin x}$ to get

\begin{align}
& \lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{4-\sqrt{16-7\sin x}}{8x} \\[8pt]
= {} &\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{4-\sqrt{16-7\sin x}}{8x} \cdot \dfrac{4+\sqrt{16-7\sin x}}{4+\sqrt{16-7\sin x}} \\[8pt]
= {} & \lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{4^2 - (16-7\sin x)}{8x(4+\sqrt{16-7\sin x})} \\[8pt]
= {} & \lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{7\sin x}{8x(4+\sqrt{16-7\sin x})} \\[8pt]
= {} & \lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\sin x}{x} \cdot \lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{7}{8(4+\sqrt{16-7\sin x})}
\end{align}

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 2):

$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{4-\sqrt{16-7\sin x}}{8x}=\\
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{4-\sqrt{16-7\sin x}}{8x}\frac{4+\sqrt{16-7\sin x}}{4+\sqrt{16-7\sin x}}=\\
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{16-{16+7\sin x}}{8x}\frac{1}{4+\sqrt{16-7\sin x}}=\\
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{{7\sin x}}{8x}\frac{1}{4+\sqrt{16-7\sin x}}=\\
\frac{7}{8}\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{{\sin x}}{x}\frac{1}{4+\sqrt{16-7\sin x}}=\\(\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{{\sin x}}{x}=1)\\
=\frac{7}{8}\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{4+\sqrt{16-7\sin x}}=\\
\frac{7}{8}\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{4+\sqrt{16-7(0)}}=\\
\frac{7}{8}\frac{1}{8}=\\
\frac{7}{64}
$$

Comment: +1 because you are the only one who writes the 'final solution' explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

View it as the derivative of $f(x) = \sqrt{16-7\sin x}$ at $x = 0$ or using the fact that $\sin x \approx x$ near $x = 0$, and expand the top expression binomially.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{4-\sqrt{16-7\sin \left(x\right)}}{8x}\right)
& =\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{4-\left(4-\frac{7x}{8}+o\left(x\right)\right)}{8x}\right)
\\& = \color{red}{\frac{7}{64}}
\end{aligned}
$$
Solved with Taylor expansion